# Como converter UNIQUEIDENTIFIER para INT?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Eai pessoal tranquilo? sou iniciante com SQL SERVER e estou em uma situação onde não sei mais como prosseguir. Tenho 2 bancos em um servidor aqui na empresa, e preciso replicar alguns dados que estão em uma tabela para outra. Porém eu preciso tratar um `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` para `INT` mas não faço a mínima ideia de como fazer isso, aparentemente é algo fácil mas não consegui encontrar nada a respeito. Segue a consulta que fiz abaixo:

```
INSERT INTO [ITControl].[dbo].[Server] (Name, IP, Description, IdPlant, IdServerType)
SELECT [IPServidor], [NomeServidor], [DescricaoServidor], [IdAmbiente], [IdTipoServidor]
FROM [BAC].[dbo].[Servidor]
WHERE [IdAmbiente] = 'FDE2C706-A103-441A-AB43-1D62517B392E' AND [IdTipoServidor] = '96F5D942-3283-4542-8D78-A4A3D8A3D208'
```

O problema em si é que no meu banco `BAC`, na tabela `Servidor` o meus dados dos campos `[IdAmbiente]` e `[IdTipoServidor]` são do tipo `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`. Já no meu outro banco chamado `ITControl` na tabela `Server` os campos que receberiam esses dados são do tipo `INT`, a minha dúvida é como eu faço para passar um `INT` no lugar do `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`? eu queria passar o valor 7 para o `[IdAmbiente]` e o valor 1 para o `[IdTipoServidor]`

Comment: se reparar o ID é uma GUID neste caso, por isso não irá funcionar passar o valor da GUID para um INT. Para resolver aconselho a criar uma tabela (ID_NOVO, ID_ANTIGO). Assim consegue ligar o id antigo para um id do tipo INT

Comment: Isso se chama dados incompatíveis, não tem como ao meu ver fazer isso, tudo que disseram é gambiarra, porque não passar o mesmo tipo para o outro banco? (modelagem errada, quase certeza, gambiarra do banco, quase outra certeza)

Comment: Pessoal aqui da empresa me auxiliou, sou estagiário ainda kkk pelo o que parece eu que não soube muito bem oq estava fazendo. vou postar a resolução

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom senhores, com auxilio dos meus colegas de equipe consegui resolver. Na minha linha onde fiz o `SELECT` (linha 2) eu apenas alterei o `[IdAmbiente]` e o `[IdTipoServidor]` para os valores que eu precisava (no caso INT de 7 e 1) e pronto! inseriu os valores que eu queria do banco `BAC` no `ITControl` substituindo os `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` para `INT`. Segue o resultado abaixo como ficou a nova consulta:

```
INSERT INTO [ITControl].[dbo].[Server] (Name, IP, Description, IdPlant, IdServerType)
SELECT [IPServidor], [NomeServidor], [DescricaoServidor], 7, 1
FROM [BAC].[dbo].[Servidor]
WHERE [IdAmbiente] = 'FDE2C706-A103-441A-AB43-1D62517B392E' AND [IdTipoServidor] = '96F5D942-3283-4542-8D78-A4A3D8A3D208'
```

Espero ter ajudado ;D